# how to do conditional css on table row?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a css that I need to work on IE8. So I cannot use last-child. 
As a trick I use

```css
table#GridViewMemory tr:first-child + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr + tr td {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

to show the 13th row of a table.
my table only have two columns

the reason I only want to show the 13th row is because this is a gridview in aspx (vb.net) and the 13th row is the pagination (a link to click page 1 page 2 page 3  and ...)

the problem is the table is not always 12 row. on the last page of the gridview. it could be anywhere between 1 to 12 row.

is it possible to check this using css .. for example:

- if 1 row then show 2nd row only
- if 2 row then show 3rd row only
- if 3 row then show 4rd row only
- ...
- ...
- ...
- if 12 row then show 13th row only

```html
    <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="">Column1</a></th><th scope="col"><a href="">Column2</a></th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31424-1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31275-1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31226-9</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30982-1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30936-5</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30915-1</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>30674-4</td><td>1</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31366-5</td><td>2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31353-2</td><td>2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31353-1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31305-1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>31273-1</td><td>2</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td colspan="2"><table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><span>1</span></td><td><a href="">2</a></td><td><a href="">3</a></td><td><a href="">4</a></td><td><a href="">5</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried using this solution but it only shows the last td cell . but not the table inside the last row. Any suggestions or comments?? Thanks

```css
table#GridViewMemory tr td[colspan="2"] {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a tfooter for your pagination, and has it got to be in a table ? To my point of view, your solution is in your script on server side ... add/remove a class , set it out the structure , whatever else

Comment: I add more information to the question. I cannot use tFooter .. . I tried to match Colspan="2" but it does not work.

Comment: maybe it is best to provide a fiddle / codepen or else with all of your css , maybe if you set display:none to tds , but [colspan] , the [colspan] table td needs to be shown too ...

Comment: I create a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/smF7b/1/ and I now have a pagerstyle cssclass on the last row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unpossible with a modern and easy way. Because IE8 is at least a crap browser. The best way is to set a class in the lastchild  with ASPX

Comment: it is of course, IMO where soltions stands, on server side script :)

Comment: I set the pagerstyle csslass to pagination. Can you help me with css http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/smF7b/1/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I figure this out! thank you